# What mcp stands for in board_ahci_mcp_linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, sata

I'm going through ahci code from given link http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ata/ahci.c and seeing mcp term quite ofen but not able to crack it down.

Can anybody let me know what mcp stands for in this code ,is it somehing generic term ?

Answer (score 0):

MCP stands for `Media Communications Processor`. It's a type of chipset made by nVidia, as you can see here : http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ich10r-sb750-780a,2374-6.html